# How to give daily updates in a flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

I am building an flutter app for our office in which I want to add a feature that gives updates on daily basis such as custom news or tasks that employees have to perform today on a collective basis please do answer this question.

Comment: Sure you can use flutter easily.You need an api for supply news and other to the employee mobile.

Comment: Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlgVI4dQC4E